# How to format expss tables? tab_cells label position and tab_cols alignment?

Tags: r, expss

Is it possible to have the tab_cells label/title wrap so that it does not cut across the columns?

Is it possible to adjust alignment of columns?

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.